# SharePoint Auto-Email Workflow Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have created several inspection forms. Each form has up to 10 questions for which a response is required if a deficiency was noted (see below).

I've created email workflows to notify me when a user has uploaded a new inspection form. The workflows works fine; however, I'd like to be able to modify the workflow to only include in each email those fields that actually have data enter. Currently, I am getting all 10 deficiency line (and associated lines), where there is data or not.

For instance, if the Line 7 - 'Inspection Results' is populated with 'NO Deficiencies Noted...', the email workflow should stop all text at that point, rather than including 10 more lines of field names with no data beside.

1. Park: Westside
2. Site Name: (P450) Westside Playground
3. Occupancy Type: Business
4. Date of Inspection: 11/8/2016
5. Inspector Name: John Doe
6. Representative's Name: Jane Doe
7. Inspection Results: No Deficiencies Noted During Inspection.
8. Deficiency No.: 1
9. Deficiency Question: Are ‘No Smoking’ signs present?
10. Deficiency Comment: There were no ‘No Smoking’ signs present.
11. Deficiency No.:
12. Deficiency Question:
13. Deficiency Comment:

Comment: One way to achieve this is to check the field value within the workflow and email different templates depending on that value. Like: `IF ('Inspection Results' = 'NO Deficiencies Noted') THEN email(7 properties) ELSE email(13 properties)`

Comment: Where would one place this field value formula. Each InfoPath form has a deficiency section with ten Question No, Form Question, and User Question Response fields. How would your formula be placed to ensure the email only sends those fields with data, every time and automatically? By the way, the first 7 fields (properties) will always have data.

Comment: To your earlier recommendation of "One way to achieve this is to check the field value within the workflow and email different templates depending on that value. Like: IF ('Inspection Results' = 'NO Deficiencies Noted') THEN email(7 properties) ELSE email(13 properties) – Gintas K Nov 29 at 11:32"; what if there is only '1' or '2' deficiencies? How would I eliminate the 'No Deficiencies Noted' field and only get the first six fields with the two deficiency fields?